# Limit of $sin(n\pi/2)$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Exercise 3.2, Question 16 from *Introduction to Real Analysis* by Bartle & Sherbert:

> Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin \frac{n\pi}{2}$ doesn't exist.

My solution so far :

$$\sin \frac{n\pi}{2} = (1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, \dots)$$
For a proof by contradiction, suppose $\lim \sin (n\pi/2)$ exists.
Let the limit be equal to $L$.
By the definition of limit of a sequence, for any $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$|\sin (n\pi/2) - L| < \epsilon$$ $\forall n \ge k$. Choosing $\epsilon = 1/2 > 0$, we have $|\sin (n\pi/2) - L| < 1/2$ $\forall n \ge k$.

---

From observation it is clear that this last step is a contradiction. But how do I proceed to show it mathematically?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Hint: if you can show that $L$ is always "far away" from infinitely many terms of the sequence $\sin n\pi/2$, you're done. Why is this?

Comment: After you chose $\varepsilon = 1/2$, for all $k\in\mathbb N$ there are both a later term of $1$ and a later term of $-1$ in the sequence. This contradicts your definition of limit of a sequence.

Comment: I've added some mathjax (see [Mathjax help page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020)) and reordered the text a little to make it more readable. If you think the original ordering was important please [edit] it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from what you've already written:

...

By the definition of limit of a sequence, for any $\varepsilon$>0, $\exists k \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $\left|\sin\frac{n\pi}{2}-L\right|<\varepsilon, \forall n \geq k$.

- If $L=0$, let $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}$, we have
  $$\exists k \in \mathbb{N},\left|\sin\frac{n\pi}{2}\right|\leq\frac{1}{2},\forall n \geq k,$$
  while when $n$ is an odd number, $\left|\sin\frac{n\pi}{2}\right|=1$, a contradiction.
- If $L>0$, let $\varepsilon=\frac{\left|L\right|}{2}$,we have
  $$\exists k \in \mathbb{N},\frac{L}{2}\leq\left|\sin\frac{n\pi}{2}\right|\leq\frac{3L}{2},\forall n \geq k,$$
  while when $n$ is an even, $\sin\frac{n\pi}{2}=0$, a contradiction.
- If $L<0$, the proof is same as above.

Comment: You only need two cases, and they can both use $\epsilon = 1/2.$ For $L\geq 0,$ you have $|f(x)-L|>\epsilon$ whenever $n\equiv 3\pmod4.$ For $L< 0,$ you have $|f(x)-L|>\epsilon$ whenever $n\equiv 1\pmod4.$

Comment: @DavidK You are correct, I didn't think so deeply, thanks for your reply.